# Show that $Log(1+z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}z^n$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Let $Log$ be the principal logarithm branch, (which is holomorphic in $\Bbb{C}-\Bbb{R_{\leq0}}$ and $Log(1)=0$. Show that $$Log(1+z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}z^n$$ for every $|z|<1$

I don't know where to start, I just need a hint to get started.

Comment: Well one way to go is to use the derivative of log and taylor series.

Comment: Hint: Taylor series.

Comment: First show that the infinite series is a branch, then show that the constant difference between $Log$ and the series is 0?